# How to change size setting of video capturing by AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I am created a app that record video and upload it on server,but video recorded at very high resolution , i want to decrease its resolution, i learn about AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 on internet but i dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if ([self.captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480]) {
    [self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can change the resolution using the `sessionPreset` property.
Default value of session preset is `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` which is suitable for high quality video and audio output.

You can set the session preset like:

```
[self.yourSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow];
```

> **sessionPreset**
>
> A constant value indicating the quality level or bitrate of the
>   output. **@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *sessionPreset Discussion**
>
> You use this property to customize the quality level or bitrate of the
>   output. For possible values of sessionPreset, see “Video Input
>   Presets.” The default value is AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh.
>
> You can set this value while the session is running.
>
> **You can only set a preset if `canSetSessionPreset`: returns YES for that
>   preset.** Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In AVCaptureSession.h

**The possible values of session preset is:**

> **Video Input Presets**
>
> Constants to define capture setting presets using the `sessionPreset`
>   property.
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720;

**Constant Details :**

> **AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings suitable for high resolution photo quality output.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```
>
> **AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings suitable for high quality video and audio output.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```
>
> **AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings suitable for output video and audio bitrates suitable for sharing over WiFi.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```
>
> **AVCaptureSessionPresetLow**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings suitable for output video and audio bitrates suitable for sharing over 3G.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```
>
> **AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings suitable for CIF quality (352x288 pixel) video output.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```
>
> **AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings suitable for VGA quality (640x480 pixel) video output.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```
>
> **AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings suitable for 720p quality (1280x720 pixel) video output.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```
>
> **AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings suitable for 1080p quality (1920x1080 pixel) video output.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```
>
> **AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings to achieve 960x540 quality iFrame H.264 video at about 30 Mbits/sec with AAC audio.
>
> QuickTime movies captured in iFrame format are optimal for editing applications.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```
>
> **AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720**
>
> ```
> Specifies capture settings to achieve 1280x720 quality iFrame H.264 video at about 40 Mbits/sec with AAC audio.
>
> QuickTime movies captured in iFrame format are optimal for editing applications.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.
> ```

Please refer : [AVCaptureSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: your description on this topic is awesome.

Comment: Do you know how to record video without setting a sessionPreset? I'm getting the error in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160407/how-do-i-record-a-video-on-ios-without-using-a-preset

Comment: very nice explanation.

Comment: Sorry, but copying the header file in here helps very little. Quality Presets do configure video resolution - but only to a small predefined set of resolutions. Not to any arbitrary resolution you want. So this is not a viable answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.2 & 3.0:

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
```

Unfortunately, this is not setup as an enum, so it currently lacks type safety since sessionPreset is a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

**2019** swift 5

```
var session : AVCaptureSession?


self.session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.medium;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to use one of these:

```
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
```

That way you don't run into a phone that doesn't support your specific specs. Unless you write code to check every time.